# conditional join according to Boolean from stored procedure-sql- server

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have this code:

```
with cte1 as (

select ...... from TABLE 1......
where ......
)

with cte2 as 
( 
select .... from table2....
where.....
)

select cte1.id,cte2.name,cte2.last from cte1 join cte2 on cte1.id=cte2.id
```

What I want is to get a bool var from stored procedure.
When it is true I don't want to do the join and don't want cte2 to be calculated.

Something like:

```
if(@BollVar=false)
select cte1.id,cte2.name,cte2.last from cte1 join cte2 on cte1.id=cte2.id
else
select cte1.id,cte1.cat from cte1 
(and here I don't want cte2 to be calculated, because I don't need it)
```

How can i do this please?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s sql-server

Comment: Can you convert cte2 to a view or a subquery?

Comment: @TerjeD. no, i can't

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte1 as (

select ...... from TABLE 1......
where ......
)

with cte2 as 
( 
select .... from table2....
where.....
)

select cte1.id,cte2.name,cte2.last from cte1
left join
cte2 on cte1.id=cte2.id
And @BollVar = 0
Where
         @BollVar = 1
         Or cte2.id is not null
```

Another way to do it is to switch to a left join that doesn't return any rows if the variable is true adding a where statement to test if the variable is true to return everything or when cte2.id is not null will make it an inner join when you actually want results.

This works because you can put pretty much whatever you want that will evaluate to true or false for the join condition.

Sorry for poorly formatting first attempt answering on my phone

Comment: i not realy get you
on , And BollVar = 0 , i think that even that the "cte2" will be calculated 

and,  where did you write "And BollVar = 0" that a conditional of the join?
and the "where" aplly even that condition not apply?

Comment: @TOOMI19876 bollVar = 0 is on the on condition of the LEFT JOIN It will mean that the left join will not return any rows when bollVar is true (1). It works. The where condition will return all rows from cte1 and none from cte2 when bollvar is true but OR it will return only rows where cte2 is found if bollvar is false. SQL doesn't care what the condition is a variable or a column it just cares if it is true or false. So the second cte is evaluated but not really because SQL will recognize the variable value and that no rows will match when it's true.

Comment: so why did you write  Or cte2.id is not null?
and are you sure that the cte2 even no be calculated  even you wrote   cte2.name,cte2.last
thanks!

Comment: Basically the or means that if bollVar = 0 then cte2.id has to be present which means it will be an inner join if you have bollvar=0. Yes even though cte2 fields will be in the query they will all be null if bollVar=1. It will execute but SQL should be able to optimize it and recognize that it doesn't have to actually join the table when bollVar=1. Try it out look at the execution plan and give it a shot. By the way a cte is like defining a view in your code it doesn't execute anything until the final select is called. There is no way of using a cte with an if then the way you want otherwise.

Comment: To do it like the if then style you show above you would have to use dynamic SQL or temp tables, or duplicate the queries with the relevant parts, this solution should keep your code lean and perform more like you want it to